# matlab error during signal analysis

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sampling

I have a set of data. basically amplitude vs time in seconds.
I need t6o find out the frequency components in the signal.
the time period = 1 second
and my sampling rate is 5000 samples per second 
when I perform the fft of the signal I get 
"undefined function 'fft' for input arguments of type 'timeseries' "
why is this so ? please help

Comment: You need to extract just the amplitude values from your time series and pass those to the `fft` function. (The `fft` function does not know what to do with the time values, which are redundant anyway, assuming a uniform constant sample rate.)

Comment: how do i extract amplitude values ? is it by using z.data command?

Comment: See e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/280210

Comment: even timeseries.data gives me a resultant time series object . how do i convert  it so that i can take an FFT ?

Answer (score 1):

`timeseries` must be a vector with complex(real) coefficients. There is probably an error related to the type of `timeseries`, make sure it's a vector (that is, it has one row (or one column)).